# VHDL Operands Have Different Lengths Error During Synthesis

Tags: concatenation, vhdl, xor, vivado

I have a code piece that concatenates two variable length vectors and XORs the result with another fixed-length vector. The variable lengths of related vectors does not affect the total length of concatenation result. Here is the respected code

```
-- Find the number of bits to be skipped.
-- This is done for better optimization of hardware.
bits2MSB := 15 - findHighestIndex(m_xorResult);

-- If there are sufficient number of remaining bits in the extended data
-- Then we can continue the XOR operation
if(bits2MSB < remainingXorCount) then
    m_xorResult         <= (m_xorResult((15 - bits2MSB - 1) downto 0) & m_dataExtended(remainingXorCount downto (remainingXorCount - bits2MSB))) xor STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(polynom, 16));
    remainingXorCount   := remainingXorCount - bits2MSB - 1; -- Decrease remainingXorCount

-- If the remaining bit count of the extended data is equal to the number of bits to be skipped until the first HIGH bit
-- Then the last XOR operation for given data can be made.
elsif(bits2MSB = remainingXorCount) then
    m_xorResult         <= (m_xorResult((14 - remainingXorCount) downto 0) & m_dataExtended(remainingXorCount downto 0)) xor STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(polynom, 16));
    remainingXorCount   := remainingXorCount - bits2MSB;
    state               <= FINISH;

-- If the remaining bits are not sufficient for a new XOR operation 
-- Then the result is equal to the extended version of the last XOR result.
else
    m_xorResult         <= (m_xorResult((14 - remainingXorCount) downto 0) & m_dataExtended(remainingXorCount downto 0));
    remainingXorCount   := 0; -- Decrease remainingXorCount
    state               <= FINISH;
end if;
```

The error message points to the line below the if statement. It says that

> [Synth 8-509] operands of logical operator '^' have different lengths (40 vs. 16)

The declaration of related vectors are as following

```
variable bits2MSB : integer range 0 to 8 := 0;
variable remainingXorCount : integer range 0 to 7 := 7;
signal m_xorResult : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
signal m_dataExtended : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(23 downto 0);
variable polynom : natural := 16#1021#;
```

In addition to these, the function findHighestIndex(...) can return an integer value in range 7 to 15.

The testbench for the given module works without any problem. I tested it for any given input to the module. Somehow, Vivado says that in some condition I can produce a length of 40 bits vector and try to XOR it with a length of 16 bit vector. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Historically a synthesis tool wouldn't event attempt this. IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) 8.6.5 Slice names "For a discrete range that appears as part of a slice name, the bounds of the discrete range shall be specified directly or indirectly as static values belonging to an integer type." Where none of the names in the expression represent static values.  That it's trying says Vivado is willing but unable. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @user1155120 I determined the range of shifting by declaring a range to my index related variables. Doesn't this help Vivado?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating variable width words to make a fixed width word, you can OR two fixed width words together, each with a variable number of bits masked out.

In outline, instead of

```
X"AAAA"(15 downto var) & X"5555"(var-1 downto 0) XOR X"1234";
```

compute

```
((X"AAAA" AND upper_mask(var)) OR (X"5555" AND not upper_mask(var))) XOR X"1234";
```

The masks can be generated by functions like this;

```
function upper_mask(var : natural) return std_logic_vector is
   mask : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '1');
begin
   mask(var - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   return mask;
end;
```

If Vivado still can't synthesise upper_mask, a loop over all bits in upper_mask should work:

```
for i in mask'range loop
   if i < var then
      mask(i) := '0';
   end if;
end loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But, my problem is not about masking. Vivado compiler couldn't resolve my variable-width vectors concatenation. I think its about the shift registers.

Comment: The answer avoids variable width vectors. Masking is only the means to that end.